# haskell: understanding types and functions

Tags: haskell

In an attempt to learn how haskell works, I created the following statements. I am trying to understand what their types are; can anybody let me know if I am the right track?

```
statement                       type
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']       ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] :: [char]

[(9,8),(7,6),(5,4)]             [(9,8),(7,6),(5,4)] :: [int a, int b] => [(a,b)]
```

if that's correct, can someone help me understand the type / function for these statements:

1. `even x = x 'mod' 1 == 1`
2. `chart x y = [y| x <- [1..x]]`

Comment: Learn the difference between types (to the right of `=>` and type classes (to the left). And: even if `Int` were a type class (which it isn't), it would still need to be capitalised.

Comment: @jwize: no, that's what tags are there for.

Comment: ``even x = ( (x `mod` 1) == 1 )`` is it clearer?

Answer (score 5):

Your type signatures are not quite correct. Pay attention to capitalisation, it's `[Char]`; and it's `Num` and not `int`; and also wrong brackets: `(Num a, Num b) => [(a, b)]`. As for the rest...

```
$ ghci
[...]
Prelude> let even x = x `mod` 1 == 1
Prelude> :t even
even :: Integral a => a -> Bool
Prelude> let chart x y = [y| x <- [1..x]]
Prelude> :t chart
chart :: (Enum t1, Num t1) => t1 -> t -> [t]
```

Also, note the backticks on the `mod`, not quotes.

**EDIT** following the comments:

It seems that you also want the clarification on the meaning of the functions `even` and `chart`.

> Even of x is the value of whether the remainder when you divide x by one is one

Unfortunately, the function is incorrectly written, since all integers are divisible by `1`, and the remainder is never `1`. The correct definition for `even` is

```
even x = x `mod` 2 == 0
```

> Even of x is the value of whether the remainder when you divide x by two is zero

As for `chart`,

> Chart of a value x and a number y is a list consisting of values y for each element in a list of numbers from 1 to x

so if you do `chart 3 5`, you will have a list of threes for each element in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], so five threes: `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: yes sorry for that its my error for not using capitalisation and on the second statement I used the wrong type of brackets, plus i acknowledge i did not use back ticks......thanks for pointing this out, I do appreciate and understand the importance of both...

Comment: on reflection of your answer, why did you use "let" in the prelude, what does that do? thanks

Comment: The interactive Haskell operates as a sequence of actions, so its syntax is slightly different than Haskell that you would write in a `.hs` file. Whereas you'd write `x = 1` in code, you need to write `let x = 1` in `ghci`. More info [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html)

Comment: i think i get it , so here I have a function add [1,2,3] 2 = [3,4,5] which takes the number 2 and adds it to each element in the list to give you a new list....so that means the type is a list of nums [Num] but what is the method to acheive this? am i right in assuming it uses curried functions here? thanks for your time

Comment: No, the type for `add` would be `Num t => [t] -> t -> [t]` (a function that takes a list, and returns a function that takes an element to return a list, all of a value that is numeric; or uncurried, a function that takes a list of numbers and a number to give a list back). The definition would be something like `add list x = [x + y | y <- list]`, or `add list x = map (+x) list` (both not curried, except for the `(+x)` bit, which is.

Comment: (Also, I hesitated to add `add = flip (map . (+))`, which is point-free and thus completely curried, because I think it would totally confuse you, but for completeness sake here it is.)

Comment: Actually, Even of x is the value of whether the remainder when you divide x by two is _zero_.

Answer (score 2):

Types in Haskell are capitalized; yes, it matters.

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] :: [Char]
```

Correct, although [Char] and String are type synonyms, and String looks nicer. :P

```
[(9,8),(7,6),(5,4)] :: (Num a, Num b) => [(a,b)]
```

Multiple constraints are in round brackets.  There's no "int" typeclass.

```
even x = x `mod` 1 == 1
even :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

Make sure you use backticks and not single quotes; yes, it matters.  In ghci use :t to check the type of mod and (==), and use :i to check the relationship between Num and Integral, and you should be able to put this together.

```
chart x y = [y | x <- [1..x]]
chart :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> b -> [b]
```

For this, you have to know the "long name" of [a..b] is enumFromTo, as well as how to desugar list comprehensions.  List comprehensions aren't hard, but there's already good descriptions in RWH, LYAH, and the Haskell 2010 Report, so I won't leave one here.

Comment: thank you all...but please help me understand are these types or functions??? 

    even x = x 'mod' 1 == 1

    chart x y = [y| x <- [1..x]]   abc [1,2,3] 1 = [6,7,8]  my trouble is understanding what these 3 mean and what their types are and whether or not they are curried function.....some further explanation would be appreciated....thank you

Comment: even is a function. Integral a => a -> Bool is a type.  chart is a function. (Enum a, Num a) => a -> b -> [b] is a type.

Comment: ahh i think i get it.....so that makes abc a function of type Num...abc [1,2,3] 1 = [6,7,8] ....is that right? thank you

Comment: does that also mean this statement has no function......           ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] :: [Char] it just has a type???

Comment: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] is "just" a value.  It is a value of type [Char].